# Missing Active Directory groups when DirectorySearcher or SearchRequest is used

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I want to list all the groups in a domain. If I use DirectorySearcher or LdapConnection and SearchRequest objects, some of the groups are missing in the returned list. But I can get the groups if I traverse all the tree with DirectoryEntry class starting from the root of the directory.

I checked the attributes of the returned and missing groups with AD Explorer tool but I could not see any difference between them. I need to use LdapConnection + SearchRequest since DirectoryEntry does not allow me to manage certificate issues if I need to use LDAP+SSL.

Did anyone enconter the same proble? What may be wrong?

Sample code for search operation;

```
LdapConnection _connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("MTS", 389));
_connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
_connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential("MTS\user1", "test123");

string _target = "dc=MTS,dc=com";

SearchRequest _request = new SearchRequest(_target, "(&(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group))", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, new string[] { "sAMAccountName" });

var _response = (SearchResponse)_connection.SendRequest(_request);

List<string> _namelist = new List<string>(16);

foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in _response.Entries)
{
      if (entry.Attributes["sAMAccountName"].Count > 0)
        _namelist.Add(entry.Attributes["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString());
}
```

**Edit 1**

If I change the search filter and search only for the missing group, it finds that group. Following search filter works and gets the group,

```
"(&(sAMAccountName=testGroup)(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group))"
```

There may be a limitation but I set Sizelimit and TimeLimit so high and search never returns an error about any limitation.

Comment: Are the missing groups always of the same type (local,  global, universal)? Did you check that they have in fact `(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group)` ?

Comment: Listed and missing groups are the same type and they are actually "(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group)". What is strange that I can retrieve them if I traverse the directory structure from top to bottom with DirectoryEntry class.

Comment: What is the total count of returned entries? From my experience directory controller may limit search response count (it depends on os, domain and forest functional level). Try using PageResultRequestControl in SearchRequest.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why I get less results than expected. Even if I set the SizeLimit too high, there is also a Max Result limitation on the server side which I can not change. This problem only occures if the domain is too big. Since I can not manipulate the size limit on the client's domain controller, I solved it by using paged search control. You can write an answer about this solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, no timeout or error but incomplete results.
I will try the PageResultRequestControl, thanks.

Comment: In my case, it seems there was some kind of timeout on the server side. The AD I was targeting is huge, so my workaround was to first do a ldap query to get all OUs. Then for each OUs doing a ldap query with s scope of Onelevel and and adpath equal to the OU's CN.